# Do multiple Azure Functions run concurrently or sequentially in the same function app?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a function app that has two functions. Both functions get their input from two different queues in the same Service Bus resource. For the function app an service plan is used, so NOT the consumption plan.

What I am not able to figure out is, if those functions are getting Triggered simultaneously/parallelly?

If I have 200 items in both of the queues, I want Function1 to retrieve a message, and then Function2, and then Function1, and then Function2, as long as the code does not process those messages at the same time (it should process them sequentially as if there was 1 function that took items from both queues one by one). Is that possible and how can I achieve this?

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Function App is a logical container of individually triggered functions. If you have an HTTP-triggered function and a message-triggered function, they do not depend on each other and will be triggered simultaneously in case an HTTP request and a message have arrived simultaneously.

Multiple message-triggered functions follow the same rule as those triggered by messages on **different** queues.

> If I have 200 items in both of the queues, I want Function1 to retrieve a message, and then Function2, and then Function1, and then Function2, as long as the code does not process those messages at the same time (it should process them sequentially as if there was 1 function that took items from both queues one by one). Is that possible, and how can I achieve this?

That's not how it works with Azure Service Bus. There's no "load balancing" or coordination between different queues. Messages will be processed by each function from each of the queues independently.

Messaging doesn't imply order. Unless you're using [message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions), it only applies to a single queue. It sounds like you have a process that you're trying to solve with messaging that might not necessarily be a good fit for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you perhaps know if if is possible to handle queue one in function1 and only if queue one is empty, function2 can do its thing with queue 2? Perhaps checking everytime function2 is hit if there are items in queue1, and if so, just return the item back to the queue2, if not, process the item? Could that be a solution?

Comment: I think you should start from formulating what's the problem you're trying to solve and not how you're doing it. It feels off to have inter-queue dependency the way you've described it.

Comment: What I want is for our application to process messages one by one. Currently I have one queue, and the app process messages one by one. But in the new situation, I will add an additional queue (priority queue), and a new function that reads from it so that the app does not need to wait for all of the messages processed in the normal queue before starting with priority messages, what is why that new queue is added.

Comment: ASB doesn't have a priority queues concept. Use message sessions if you need to process messages in the order of their sending. You could have several sessions, a `normal` session and a `priority` session, and when sending messages, specify one of the two sessions. If you send fewer messages to the priority session, those will be processed faster. But if you have two functions, one per queue, there should be no inter-dependency between the two.